# Étymologie de « est-ce que »

Tags: grammaire, étymologie

> La particule postverbale « -ti » a été notée pour la première fois dans Gaston Paris (1887). « Ti, signe d'interrogation. » Romania 6.438-442. Au XIXe siècle, cette particule était encore le moyen le plus répandu pour indiquer l'interrogation dans les dialectes de la langue d'oïl. Par contre, dans les variétés du français populaire dérivées de la koinè de Paris autres que celles parlées en Amérique du Nord, elle a été évincée au profit de la particule esk en position de complémenteur : « On a gagné » (indicatif) → « Esk on a gagné? » (interrogatif), Wittmann, Henri, « Grammaire comparée des variétés coloniales du français populaire de Paris du XVIIe siècle et origines du français québécois. » Le français des Amériques, dir. Robert Fournier & Henri Wittmann, 281-334. Trois-Rivières: Presses universitaires de Trois-Rivières (lire en ligne[PDF]).

Cela est la note numéro 43 de la page de Wikipédia Française sur [le Français Québécois] (https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois). Il paraît donc que "est-ce que" soit une manière de reconstruire l'étymologie de cett particule interrogative "esk". Mais est-ce correcte? Est-ce vrai que "esk" nous a donné est-ce que? Et d'où vient-il, cet "esk"?

Comment: Si un linguiste martien était venu étudier notre langue sans matériel écrit, c'est-à-dire de façon absolument synchronique, peut-être qu'il raisonnerait ainsi :) Comme par contre on retrouve ce mot à l'orthographe habituelle dans beaucoup de documents on parvient à une autre conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ne trouve nulle part de source d'une hypothétique particule ***esk*** qui serait antérieure à la forme ***est-ce que***.

Il ne peut donc s'agir que d'une retranscription phonétique de la structure interrogative *[**est-ce que**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/est-ce%20que)* qui est attestée depuis longtemps en français. Voir aussi [Interrogation périphrastique](http://gabrielwyler.com/page492.html#Interrogationp%C3%A9riphrastique-est-cequeprislitt%C3%A9ralement), Gabriel Wyler.

Comme toutes les locutions, ***est-ce que*** doit être considéré comme un tout.  L'écrire ***esk*** est une manière astucieuse d'insister sur son irréductibilité mais il ne faut pas prendre *esk* au pied de la lettre, lui chercher une autre origine que phonétique ou une existence officielle en français.

En revanche, la graphie *esk*, et ses dérivés *eske* / *eski*, se retrouvent comme marqueurs interrogatifs dans beaucoup de créoles à base lexicale française.

Answer (score 1):

La question posée par un utilisateur demande qu’on interprète, à la lumière de l’étymologie, la portée d’un texte linguistique lu sur Wikipédia, soit la note 43 de l’article *Français québécois*.

L’article porte sur une variété du français populaire issue d’une koïnè parlée au 17e siècle à Paris et dans d’autre centres urbains de la France. En partant, on n’est pas dans un registre qui fait appel au français standard, une variété qui se transmet par l’école avec des conventions orthographiques bien arrêtées. Dans la note, il est question, avec référence aux auteurs Paris (1887) et Wittmann (1995), de deux particules interrogatives, *-ti* et *esk-* qui, en compétion, ont marqué l’évolution de la koïnè pour aboutir à des usages divergents dans les variétés du français populaire *parlées* en Europe et dans les Amériques.

Dans leurs publications scientifiques respectives, les deux auteurs cités expliquent les origines et l’histoire des deux particules. Gaston Paris dérive *-ti* de *-t-il* et note qu’il est encore en usage dans les “patois” régionaux de l’Europe francophone alors que Henri Wittmann démontre que *-ti* est la particule interrogative en usage dans les parlers populaires des Amériques, avec la variante *-tu* au Québec. Quant à *esk*, Wittmann la dérive de la périphrase *est-ce que* et note que son usage s’étend aux variétés du français populaire d’Europe et à la plupart des variété du créole français.

Du côté théorique, Tesnière admet au moins dès 1959 que la particule interrogative *esk* tirée de la périphrase *est-ce que* est une particule opaque et indivise du français parlé, une position qui aujourd'hui fait consensus parmi les linguistes. Plus de détail sur [Google.](https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&ei=M6bPW67jLNPS_wSZ0aSwAQ&q=esk+interrogative&oq=esk+interrogative&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20428.22719.0.27034.10.10.0.0.0.0.191.1694.0j10.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.370...0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.YwbiwpQN3R8)

Diachroniquement, c’est à dire si on veut suivre l’historique de la perte de transparence qui affecte cette  particule, le passage de *est-ce que* à *esk* constitue un cas d’[univerbation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univerbation), soit le résultat d’un processus par lequel une expression figée issue d’une périphrase est condensée en un mot simple et indivis.

Comment: *MickG*, dans sa question, demande si c’est correct de dire que « *est-ce que* [est] la  bonne manière de reconstruire l’étymologie de [la] particule *esk* », telle que soutenue dans l’article *Français québécois* de Wikipédia et fondée sur un avis d’experts (au sens que l’entend la Wikipédia). La réponse à cette question ne peut être que « oui », point à la ligne.

Comment: Oui, il est possible d'interpréter cette phrase et la question qui suit de la sorte. Cependant, les deux questions qui suivent (**Est-ce vrai que "esk" nous a donné "est-ce que" ?  Et d'où vient-il, cet "esk"?**)  montrent que ce n'est pas ce qu'en a saisi MickG, puisqu'elles sous entendent sans ambiguïté qu'il comprend que la forme *esk* est à l'origine de *est-ce que*. Je n'ai répondu qu'à ces deux questions et c'était probablement une erreur de ma part. Je vais essayer de la corriger.

Comment: Ce n’est pas parce que *MickG* s’enfarge dans une phrase sur trois qu’il n’est pas clair que: (1) il a bien lu et, sur le fond, compris l’article de Wikipédia; (2) il cherche à confirmer ce que dit l’article, soit que *est-ce que* est l’étymologie ultime de la particule *esk*; (3) il veut savoir comment, en étymologie, on vient à reconstruire cet *esk*, un quelque chose qu’il comprend quand même que tous les linguistes reconnaissent comme une particule productive. Il faut lui laisser ça, non? DONC, Il suffit d’ajouter à la réponse que, historiquement, il s’agit d’un cas d’univerbation.

Comment: L'univerbation n'est pas (encore ?) réalisée à l'écrit en français. Il est clair que nous n'avons pas la même lecture de sa question mais laissons MickG juger de ce qu'il avait compris ou pas. Il peut tout à fait "désaccepter" ma réponse et accepter la tienne s'il le souhaite. Ce n'est pas un problème.

Comment: Qui qui parle des incohérences du français écrit? On parle du français parlé, camarade.

Comment: @jlliagre Congratulations, you learned here what *univerbation* is all about and used it already in a new edit answering the question *Is “Au jour d'hui” one, two, or three words?*, just two hours ago. I'm impressed.

Comment: Les mots me manquent pour t'exprimer ma gratitude ! J'ai aussi appris ici le verbe *s'enfarger* mais n'ai pas eu encore l'occasion de l'utiliser. Chez moi, on dit *s'embroncher* ;-)

Comment: *S'embroncher*, c'est cute. Marseille ?

Comment: Pile-poil !!!!!

Comment: Merci, je vais essayer de m'en servir, oralement d'abord, vendredi soir avec les copains.