# Les différents langages du français

Tags: oral, registre

Je sais que l'utilisation du français à l'écrit est assez différent du français oral avec par exemple 'maintenant' à l'écrit et "mainant" à l'oral. " il y a " à l'écrit et "y'a" à l'oral, "je peux" et "j'peux" etc etc.

Dans les pays étrangers, lorsque l'on apprend le français et que ensuite l'on vient en France, tout est très différent et c'est parfois compliqué de comprendre lorsque les gens parlent puisque pour nous c'est un peu comme une nouvelle langue car les personnes parlent avec un langage moins soutenu/scolaire et n'emploient pas les mots comme on les écrit comme je l'ai montré dans mon premier paragraphe.

Je sais également que le langage dans certains quartiers est très différents des deux autres langages ( langage écrit et oral ) avec beaucoup de mots aux syllabes inversées "merci" qui devient "ci-mer" ... et l'emploi de mots non utilisés par le "reste" de la population "moula, condé, la hess, ...".

Outre ces trois types de langages français comme je les appelle, savez-vous si il en existe d'autres et savez-vous notamment si cela est certifié ou quelque chose comme ça, par exemple un dictionnaire pour le français oral ou "de rue" ? Egalement, pourquoi ces différences assez grandes je trouve qu'on ne retrouve par exemple pas dans les autres langues à travers le monde ( du moins celles que je parle régulièrement ).

Merci d'avance pour vos explications

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenu sur FL, c'est une question intéressante, mais trop ouverte pour ce site. Si tu as des questions précises sur les variétés et les registres du français, je t'encourage à les poser (en utilisant les tags appropriés comme *oral* ou *registre*). Si tu cherches un exposé général sur la question tu peux aussi poser une question pour demander des ressources.

Answer (score 10):

Comme l'écrivait déjà Louis Meigret en 1530 :

> *Nous écrivons un langage qui n'est point en usage, et usons d'une langue qui n'a point
>   d'écriture en France.* Cité par Bernard Cerquiglini, *L'accent du souvenir*, 1995.

On peut en effet dire, en première approximation, qu'il existe aujourd'hui deux langues françaises, la langue écrite, conservatrice, normée, enseignée à l'école, ayant peu évolué depuis XIV<sup>e</sup> siècle et la langue parlée qui s'en éloigne, plus flexible et variée. On peut aussi considérer qu'il y a deux langues parlées. La première reste rigide et correspond directement à l'écrit. C'est celle de la lecture, de la récitation, des discours officiels, du texte lu au prompteur par les journalistes alors que la deuxième est la langue utilisée spontanément dans la vie de tous les jours. Réciproquement, cette dernière peut être écrite, par exemple dans des messageries instantanées, twitter, les SMS (textos), dans les forums de discussions, etc.

Certains locuteurs francophones ne sont pas conscients de cette dualité, et considèrent à tort que seule la langue écrite est la langue correcte et donc que la langue parlée spontanée est plus ou moins incorrecte, voire « fausse ».

La langue « écrite parlée » met en évidence le caractère peu phonétique du français écrit puisque de nombreuses lettres ne correspondent à aucun son et qu'ils faut connaître « par cœur » la prononciation de certains mots, ou choisir la prononciation correcte en fonction du contexte. Parmi les langues voisines du français, seul l'anglais nous « surpasse » dans ce domaine.

La langue écrite comporte de nombreuses règles et conventions qui n'ont pas de sens à l'oral. La plupart des pluriels ne s'entendent pas sauf en cas de liaison ou de pluriel spécifique (chevaux), les terminaisons homophones ou proches qui sont la source de nombreuses fautes à l'écrit (par exemple : -ais, -ait, -ai, -aie, -er, -é, -et) n'ont pas d'effet sur la prononciation.

Dans la langue « parlée parlée », la prononciation est souvent simplifiée par rapport à la prononciation du français écrit. C'est par exemple le cas :

- de ***maintenant***, dont le T s'amuit fortement et se transforme en N pour arriver à la prononciation courante « **main'nant** » avec gémination du N : /**mɛ̃nnɑ̃**/
- des pronoms personnels ***je***, ***tu*** devant voyelle, ***il(s)*** et ***elle(s)*** transformés respectivement en :
  — ***ch'*** : ***je sais*** bien → ***ch'ais*** bien;
  — ***t'*** : ***tu as*** raison → **t'as** raison;
  — ***y*** : ***Il*** part → **Y** part;
  — ***è*** : ***Elle*** ne vient pas → **È** vient pas.

***Il*** devenu ***y*** se confond avec le pronom ***y*** qui suit dans l'expression ***il y a*** qui devient donc à l'oral ***y'a***.

La grammaire du français parlé présente aussi quelques différences significatives.

- Les phrases interrogatives qui ne font quasiment jamais appel à l'inversion verbe-sujet :
  ***Y vas-tu ?*** → Est-ce que tu y vas ? → "[**Eske**](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29470/%C3%89tymologie-de-est-ce-que/32134)" **t'y vas ?**
  *Y vas-tu ? → Tu y vas ? → **T'y vas ?***
- La première personne du pluriel  a disparu, remplacée par la troisième personne du singulier :
  ***nous partons*** → ***on part***.
- Le *ne* de la négation a disparu :
  ***Je ne veux pas*** → ***Ch'veux pas***
- Le remplacement du passé simple par le passé composé :
  *Il **naquit** à Ajaccio* → *Il **est né** à Ajaccio*.
  Le passé simple disparaît aussi à l'écrit, mais plus lentement.
- La rareté des appositions :
  *Tout en conduisant, il téléphone* → *il téléphone en conduisant / il téléphone au volant*
- Le doublement sujet-pronom plus fréquent :
  *Laure a raison* → *Laure, **elle** a raison*.

Le français écrit ne garde pas la trace des hésitations, des corrections, des reprises de phrase, trace normalement supprimée quand on passe du brouillon au document final alors qu'il est impossible de faire de même à l'oral. Ceci n'est bien sûr pas spécifique au français.

Les autres points cités dans la question (***cimer, moula, condé,*** etc.) posent des problèmes à un apprenant mais peuvent poser les mêmes à un francophone peu familier avec le sociolecte auquel appartiennent les expressions rencontrées. Le vocabulaire n'est pas ce qui caractérise le plus une langue. Il peut varier plus ou moins significativement en fonction de la population ou des modes sans changer fondamentalement une langue. Malgré l'omniprésence de mots français en anglais, personne ne conteste le caractère germanique de cette langue.

Il ne faut finalement pas sous-estimer la composante individuelle, que ce soit dans la langue écrite où chaque écrivain ou rédacteur a son propre style, sa liberté d'écriture et la langue parlée où chaque locuteur a lui aussi sa ou plutôt ses langues parlées, qu'il va adapter en fonction de ses interlocuteurs, de son humeur, de l'endroit où il se trouve, etc. Il n'existe donc pas **deux** langues françaises, mais des continuums de langues et de registres dont chacun d'entre nous, avec plus ou moins de bonheur, est dépositaire.

Comment: Magnifique réponse merci beaucoup

Comment: La distinction orale/écrit est un peu limitée. Il y a de l'oral contrôlé (comme un discours ou la présentation d'un journal télévisé), de l'écrit spontané (messageries instantanées, Twitter) en plus des catégories que tu cites, c'est plutôt un spectre comme tu le dis en fin de réponse qu'une dualité comme tu le dis au début.

Answer (score 3):

J'aimerais rajouter aux autres réponses que oui, il y a bien des dictionnaires "de rue". Par exemple, le bien nommé [dico2rue](http://www.dico2rue.com/) ou le [dictionnaire de la zone](https://www.dictionnairedelazone.fr/).

Le premier est tenu par la communauté donc la fiabilité n'est pas forcément énorme, mais de toute façon le langage de la rue évolue constamment.

Il y a aussi un système de vote qui permet d'avoir une certaine idée du consensus de la définition. L'orthographe peut varier pas mal aussi.

C'est pas parfait mais c'est quand même un bon début.

Answer (score 1):

Le Français oral et écrit se différencie effectivement, en revanche l'exemple choisit n'est pas forcément le plus pertinent, là où cette prononciation est courante dans le Sud de la France, elle l'est beaucoup moins dans le centre / Nord.

De manière général on aura tendance à plutôt éviter de prononcer certaines voyelles, *maintenant* se prononcera plutôt *maintnant*, *je suis* deviendra *jsuis* voir même *chui* (j'ai souvenir d'avoir déjà vu cet exemple dans une autre réponse, ta question est peut-être dupliquée).

Effectivement dans le langage familier le verlan (envers) est parfois utilisé, surtout dans les quartiers et *ci-mer* est un exemple d'actualité, les autres sont généralement des mots issus de l'arabe ou d'un très vieil argot, *la daronne* (pour mère) etc...

En revanche je ne suis pas d'accord avec ta qualification comme *type de langages*, le premier est seulement une simplification orale, comme cela se fait dans beaucoup d'autres langues (en anglais par exemple). Le second (le verlan) est très spécifique et ne s'utilise plus beaucoup, et le dernier vient simplement de l'utilisation de mots provenant comme je l'ai dit de l'arabe ou d'un vieil argot (cela dépendra donc fortement de la zone géographique également).

Comment: Qu'est-ce que l'emploi de "les quartiers" sans adjectif (3eme paragraphe) veut dire? Ca me fait penser a l'usage de "the Hood" en anglais comme argot/raccourci pour "neighborhood" (qui peut etre pejoratif, mais pas toujours, suivant le context).

Comment: I don't know the exact translation in English, it means the bad area of the cities where it's populated mostly by poor and immigrates / usually low educated people. They tend to use more Verlan and Arabs / argot words (les darons = les parents, les condé etc etc)

Comment: Merci beaucoup pour votre réponse

Comment: @PapaPoule Highly interesting comment and I'm amazed the question hasn't been asked on FL over the years. This use (always plural no adjective, if any it would be *défavorisés* or [*sensibles*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_urbaine_sensible) as used [here](https://www.lepoint.fr/politique/banlieue-les-quartiers-attendent-plus-du-gouvernement-13-06-2019-2318654_20.php)) must has spread over the last 20 years. *Quartiers* are usually associated with peripheral areas ("inner cities" in the US). There's no positive connotation to the word as "hood" can have, maybe closer to "ghetto".

Comment: @stbr Saying this in a **friendly way**, with the storm falling upon SE and its CoC (present and coming) we should be careful in what we write. I personally think some words that can have a derogatory feel to them should not be used. e.g.  -  "bad" as used in your sentence is a moral judgement,  poor or immigrant (which is sometimes the case with those who live in those deprived areas),  does not mean "bad"  ;  -  "low educated" as well, different cultures have different education, what is "bad'" for one might not be for the other.

Comment: « les autres sont généralement des mots issus de l'arabe » et du romani, du berbère, du portugais…

Answer (score 0):

Non locuteur natif. Je veux rajouter aux autres réponses que même un seul mot peut avoir des significations différentes selon le registre de français utilisé. Prenons par exemple le mot « brasser ».

En fait, selon le wiktionnaire il existe deux verbes avec la même orthographe.

> (Verbe 1) Du gaulois bracis, passé au latin populaire *braciare, de
>   braces (« blé blanc, malt »), apparenté à braise (« drêche »), brai.
>   Le sens étymologique est proche de « (faire) fermenter ». Il a subi
>   l’influence sémantique de bras dans certains de ses sens. La véritable
>   orthographe serait non brasser, puisque le mot ne vient pas de bras,
>   mais bracer, comme on l'écrivait autrefois1.
>
> (Verbe 2) Dénominal de bras ou brasse.

Le premier a plusieurs sens, entre autres :

(Par analogie) Mouvoir, agiter en vue d’une opération.

Brasser du métal, des cuirs, des épingles, des clous.

et

(Jeux) Mélanger des cartes ou tout autre objet.

Brasser les cartes, les dés, les feuilles.

Le second en a deux,

(Marine) Mouvoir les bras d’une vergue pour changer la direction de la voile qu’elle porte.

Nager la brasse.

**Il existe même un sens argotique :**

> Ce bâtard il a brassé avec son album, il a fait 20 000 ventes la
>   première semaine.
>
> Brasser est un verbe désignant le fait de faire de l’argent, de
>   manière légale ou non.

On trouve ça dans le dictionnaire "alternatif" urbandico.

http://www.urbandico.com/definition/brasser/

Answer (score -2):

On ne conçoit pas qu'il s'agisse d'un nouveau langage lorsque l'on considère certaines formes que prend le langage dans la langue parlée mais on conçoit qu'il existe deux niveaux de formalité. La même chose se retrouve dans l'anglais. Il ne faut pas considérer que toutes les élisions phonétiques sont la marque de l'informel. Prenons le cas de « maintenant » que vous citez. Que ce mot soit prononcé « maintenant » ou « maintnant » il n'en reste pas moins dans ces deux prononciations un mot de la langue standard ; il s'agit de deux accents qui sont également considérés comme de la prononciation soutenue ; il n'existe pas de graphie pour cette seconde prononciation.

- Dans la prononciation, il se fait beaucoup d'élisions qui ne se marquent pas dans l'écriture, comme « Une heure, quatre ans » (prononcez «  Un'heure, quatr'ans  ») (Ac. 1798-1878)

Si l'on se penche sur la locution « il y a » ce n'est plus le même problème ; il est ici question d'une ellipse, c'est à dire de la suppression d'un mot et plus de celle d'un son. Toutes les ellipses ne transforment pas l'énoncé dans lequel elles ont une incidence en langage informel, mais c'est le cas pour celle-ci. En passant de « il y a » à « y'a » on ne passe toujours pas d'un langage à un autre mais d'un registre à un autre, du registre courant au registre familier (autrement appelé registre informel).

Normalement, un bon enseignement du français doit prendre en compte le type de variante auquel vous référez dans votre premier paragraphe, cela parce qu'elles font partie du français en tant que langue. C'est lorsque l'on passe à je dirai une « langue connexe » que vous êtes pleinement justifié dans votre critique ; j'ai personnellement appris le français tout jeune en tant que langue maternelle et je connais quelques mots d'argot parce qu'ils sont passés dans le langage mais si je devais converser en pur argot comme certaines personnes en sont capable je ne comprendrais pas la moitié de ce qui se dit et ne pourrait probablement pas formuler 99 % de mes idées les plus simples correctement ; notons entre parenthèses qu'il ne faut pas compter sur l'argot pour formuler les idées de nature plus philosophiques ou littéraires: c'est bien connu, les argots ne sont pas véritablement des langues mais des sortes de dialecte édifiés en grande partie dans les circonstances les plus terre à terre par ces sections de population les plus terre à terre ou moralement les plus viles (la pègre).

Dans cette considération de l'argot français on a l'exemple le plus important de langue connexe, ce n'est pas le seul. On trouve les rejetons suivants listé par ordre d'importance.

- argot
- franglais
- verlan
- parler branché
- sabir

  Un [argot](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argot), nous dit l'encyclopédie libre, « est un langage ou vocabulaire particulier qui se crée à l'intérieur de groupes sociaux ou socio-professionnels déterminés *et par lequel l'individu affiche son appartenance au groupe et se distingue de la masse des sujets parlants* », la distinction qui est faite dans la phrase suivant cette assertion étant essentielle à une définition plus précise :  « C'est un sociolecte qu'il faut distinguer du jargon, qui est propre aux représentants d'une profession ou d'une activité commune se caractérisant par un lexique spécialisé. ».

  Le [franglais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franglais) n'est pas une langue dans un aussi grand degré que l'argot mais il tend fortement  à le devenir ([réf.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franglais#H%C3%A9g%C3%A9monie_de_l'anglais)). Cette couleur qui est donnée au français par la forte invasion de formes anglaises devenant souvent dans le français du jargon et perdant leur nature anglaise est toujours rejetée par de nombreux français ([réf.](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franglais#Lutte_contre_le_franglais)) ; cependant, à mon avis, ce phénomène d'invasion de la langue n'arrête pas de croitre en importance.

  Le [verlan](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlan) est essentiellement basé sur une reconstruction des noms en inversant les syllabes (femme → meuf) et parfois en inversant les mots dans les expressions (comme ça → ça comme).

  Le [parler branché](https://fandefle.com/2013/09/20/parlez-djeuns-soyez-branches/) se caractérise comme suit.
  C'est plutôt une couleur apportée au langage qu'un langage à proprement parler et il est créé et utilisé par certains adolescents. Il s´agit d´un mélange d´anglicismes, de mots raccourcis ou de verlan. Les jeunes ont aussi tendance à utiliser les superlatifs à tout bout de champ (« super », « trop »).
  J'ajoute qu'il est fortement caractérisé par des redéfinitions de sens (« Tu me fais mal délirer. », par exemple).

  Le [sabir](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/sabir/) est un mélange de langues romanes et d'arabe. Son importance dans le français est quasi-négligeable.

« Ci-mer » est évidemment du verlan, mais les autres termes comme « moula », « la hess », et « labès » sont de récentes introductions dues aux populations arabes ; on en trouve de bien plus anciennes provenant de l'arabe, comme « chouia » et « toubib » mais elles n'ont toujours pas un degré  de francisation bien grand ; elles sont limitées au domaine du dialogue dans une certaine littérature et on n'emploi toujours pas « toubib » comme synonyme de « docteur » ni « un chouia » comme synonyme de « un peu » dans le langage formel ni même couramment dans le langage familier ; ce vocabulaire demeure ce qu'il a toujours été, du vocabulaire très marginal. Le terme « condé » est du pur argot français qui signifie « policier » ou « gendarme » ; il est de ce fait plus courant mais en tant qu'argot il n'a pas acquis comme le mot d'argot  « flic » le même succès à s'introduire dans la langue familière  et demeure un terme beaucoup plus vulgaire.

Bien sûr, il existe des dictionnaires de l'argot traditionnel et des recueils de toutes sortes d'argots de groupe ; par exemple le recueil trouvé sur le site [vocabulaire gay](https://www.mecamarier.com/glossary/) donne une liste des mots utilisés par toutes sortes de personnes non hétérosexuelles qui est appelée liste de vocabulaire, mais ce n'est qu'un argot de groupe qui n'a pas la qualité de vocabulaire standard dans beaucoup de cas (broute gazon, camionneuse). La certification que ces dictionnaires et recueils apportent à l'usage ne consiste en aucune certification au niveau de la langue standard, laquelle vous devez rechercher dans les dictionnaires courants. Vous n'êtes pas tenu en tant qu'utilisateur étranger du français d'être familier avec cette masse de vocabulaire soit à peine reconnue par la majorité des français eux-mêmes soit redondante et n'apportant pratiquement rien à la langue française. À moins d'avoir un intérêt particulier dans l'étude de ces vocabulaires marginaux on perd son temps en ne le passant pas à l'étude de la langue standard.

La différence du point de vue de la formalité ne me semble pas significativement différente de ce que l'on trouve en anglais par exemple, le seul langage que je connaisse suffisamment pour essayer d'établir un rapport. Il faut savoir cependant qu'un dictionnaire d'Oxford a recensé jusqu'à 500 000 mots et que l'anglais moderne compterait plus d'un million de mots alors que le français ne compterait au plus que 200 000 mots (dont 30 000 de vocabulaire courant).
La question de savoir si le français serait en fait unique dans le sens de constituer une diversité plus grande des formes d'expression me dépasse un peu. Je crois que jusqu'à une époque pas si lointaine le français comme l'anglais avait son argot traditionnel et ses variantes régionales, qui depuis longtemps sont sur la pente d'une régression et il n'était pas fondamentalement différent à ce point de vue, n'offrait probablement pas une plus riche variété,  pour ce qu'elle pouvait avoir de valeur.  Le phénomène que vous constatez serait d'origine assez récente et donc pas aussi profond que vous pourriez le penser, encore superficielle ; on le doit apparemment à l'histoire récente : la forte influence économique et culturelle du monde anglo-saxon, l'introduction de populations en provenances des anciennes colonies et ce qui pourrait bien être une réaction de la jeunesse stimulée dans sa créativité par sa nouvelle ouverture à la culture anglo-saxonne et d'autres ; cette créativité de la jeunesse, loin d'être non existante par le passé, était plutôt limitée à l'argot des écoles.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99716/discussion-on-answer-by-lph-les-differents-langages-du-francais).